# Unable to upload file to bucket using 3-legged access token

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am currently following "[Upload Files to BIM 360 Document Management](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-6-upload-the-file-to-the-storage-object)" and I'm stuck on step 6 where I'm suppose to upload to the client's bucket using 3-legged access token.

So...am I doing something wrong for step 6, or the guide is outdated?

From reading the [PUT   buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/) documentation, only 2-legged access token can access this API.

expected:
200 (and whatever json data it returns)

actual:
403

```
{
    "reason": "Only 2 legged service tokens are allowed to access this api."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately some of the OSS (bucket) endpoints only support 2 legged auth and PUT Object is obviously one of them so you will need another 2 legged token for the upload...

The guide is not exactly outdated but apparently that's an oversight there...

Comment: So...how do I, as a third party app, help user (that is not myself) to upload their model to their bucket, on their behalf using 2-legged token?  

(I am confused at how I'm going to write an app that manages user's data as a third party app when I couldn't call the OSS API to upload their model to their own bucket)

Comment: No bucket requests are authenticated on a Forge app level and not the end users - when they create buckets/upload files they do so with the creds of your Forge app and they authenticate thru the user mgt layer of your app and you don't create an app for each and every one of them right - and when it comes to B360 all files are uploaded to a special, general (called wip.prod) bucket and in that case 2 legged token from your own Forge app is sufficient.